# Has the molecular diatomic oxygen trianion been observed or predicted?

Tags: ions, molecules

Has diatomic oxygen ever been observed with a 3− charge, i.e. $\ce{O_2^{3-}}$? Have any ab intio calculations been done on this ion?

Update:

Just to summarize some of the answers below and add my two cents, it seems that no studies have reported observing this ion experimentally, either in isolation or as part of a condensed phase. Ab initio calculations suggest that $\ce{O_2^{3-}}$ is unstable in isolation, meaning that the loss of an electron is exothermic. However, first-principles calculations have predicted that a molecular oxygen trianion can exist as part of a solid; see [Phys. Rev. B 85, 035210 (2012)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103%2FPhysRevB.85.035210).

Comment: Two things: firstly, when referring to oxidation states, the sign comes before the number, so a thing is in oxidation state +3 or -1, for example. Secondly, an *atom* has an oxidation state, a molecule has a *charge*. For charges, the sign comes after, so 2- or 2+.

Comment: One should notice that the simple existence of such a species is not obvious. Anions always have the possibility to evolve through loss of an electron, which is not the case for positively charged species.  Computation of electron affinities is not obvious, as ab initio calculations would "force" the electron to remain bound. Therefore one has to add numerous diffuse orbitals and consider that the presence of the extra electron in diffuse orbitals should be interpreted as a sign of unstability of these species.

Comment: anions form from Gain of electrons and cations form from Loss of electrons. Not the other way around.

Comment: Could you quote the section where they predict the oxygen trianion, please. I was unable to find any such reference, but I am not an expert on polarons and I might have missed it.

Comment: They don't use the word "trianion", but I think what they describe on p. 2 is equivalent: "We found that the presence of an excess electron in Li$_2$O$_2$ results in elongation and/or cleavage of one of the O–O bonds...and the excess electron is localized at the cleaved O–O site."

Comment: I do not see how this can be considered equivalent to the statement of a trianion. It should also be mentioned, that the calculations treat one polaron in a 192 atom super cell; that is one extra electron per 96 oxygen atoms and the electron is located at the site where the oxygen bond is broken or elongated. This is just a little bit more stable than having an delocalised excess electron in a perfect lithium peroxide lattice.

Answer (score 4):

According to "[Small Multiply Charged Anions as Building Blocks in
Chemistry](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ar960147o)" Acc. Chem. Res. 1996, 29, 497-502

> it is concluded that all isolated diatomic dianions or
>   other multiply charged diatomic anions are not stable
>   to loss of an extra electron or fragmentation in their
>   ground electronic states

So even $\ce{O2^{2-}}$, let alone $\ce{O2^{3-}}$ cannot exist in isolation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of (and a quick search couldn't reveal) any studies on the $\ce O_2^{3-}$ ion. Note that in this ion, oxygen wouldn't have an oxidation state of –3, but –1.5.

Answer (score 2):

The $\ce{O2^{3-}}$ ion is predicted hy electronic calculations in the high pressure compound $\ce{FeO2}$[[1](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-017-13312-4)]. This oxide, believed to exist deep in Earth's mantle, is computed to have the sigma antibonding orbital between the oxygen atoms lies within the $t_{2g}$ electronic band associated with octahedral coordination of the iron atoms. This causes an electron that would normally be associated with the iron coordination sphere to be transferred to the oxygen-oxygen sigma antibond, converting the peroxide ion from $\ce{O2^{2-}}$ to $\ce{O2^{3-}}$ (and the iron from iron(II) to iron (III)).

Also noted is the impact on bond length between the oxygen atoms. With the extra electron in the dioxygen function going into an antibonding orbital, the oxygen-oxygen bond length in $\ce{FeO2}$ is found to be 1.89 Å versus approximately 1.49 Å typically found in ordinary peroxides.

**Reference**

1. Sergey S. Streltsov, Alexey O. Shorikov, Sergey L. Skornyakov, Alexander I. Poteryaev & Daniel I. Khomskii (2017). "Unexpected 3+ valence of iron in FeO2, a geologically important material lying “in between” oxides and peroxides". *Sci Rep* **7**, 13005. https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-017-13312-4.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is, in $\ce{H3O2}$. This is from an a CCB bond. However, this is highly unlikely.

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate in your answer on this?