# Naming Ionic Compounds with Transition Metals

Tags: formal-charge

Look at $\ce{FeO2}$.  We know that $\ce{O2}$
is $-2$ then we must have $-4$ for $\ce{Fe}$

So $\ce{Fe}$ must have $+4$ charge so then is it $\ce{Fe(IV)}$ ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i found that there is only Fe with  2+ and 3+ charge so how do i got 4+ thanx

Comment: try using $Fe_2O_3$ instead.

Comment: $\ce{FeO2}$ does not exist.

Comment: @bon [Apparently it does.](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-13312-4) At least, if your laboratory is in the lower mantle. This "peroxide" [may even contain $\ce{O2^{3-}}$ instead of the usual perocide ion.](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-13312-4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [the Wikipedia article for iron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron):

> Like other group 8 elements, iron exists in a wide range of oxidation states, −2 to +6, although +2 and +3 are the most common.

Thus, assigning $\ce{FeO2}$ as an iron(IV) compound is not something that is impossible, but it is unlikely. There are only a few compounds with that are iron(IV).

A more likely scenario is that $\ce{FeO2}$ may contain [other anions of oxygen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen#Compounds):

- Oxide $\ce{O^2-}$
- Superoxide $\ce{O2^-}$
- Peroxide $\ce{O2^2-}$
- Ozonide $\ce{O3^-}$

While oxide is the most common anion, there is another on the list above that is reasonably common. Which is it? If you have that anion, what is your oxidation number for iron?

Comment: I'm afraid iron(II) peroxide is is even more unlikely.

Comment: However OP may ask about hemoglobin with oxygen bound to Fe

Comment: FeO2 may be formed under high pressure and even exist in Earth's mantle. [This answer]( https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/179647/17175) references an article suggesting it actually cobtains iron(III)  and $\ce{O2^{3-}}$.